# Create a loop that contains a function with 2 or more arguments

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I have a function and I need to run it on over 100 DataFrames so I used the following:

```
def Routine(arg1)
    #do something

for idx, df in enumerate([df_AAPL, df_AMD, df_AMZN]):
    Routine(df)
```

Now the above works but now I realize I need to add another argument to the above function. How would I edit my loop to accept 2 or more args such as:

```
def Routine(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: How about a default value? `Routine(arg1, arg2=None)` If `arg2==None` do x, if `arg2!=None` do y.

Comment: Also, look at [Single/Double Asterisk](https://blog.guvi.in/python-single-double-asterisk/).

Comment: Do you want for each dataframe some unique argument?